# Euler -> Quat: Flipped: 90 == -270

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions

i am playing around with quaterions, matrices, euler rotations. For some reason when converting from euler to quaternion to euler my angles are flipped.

So where i expect 90, i get -270.

30 stays 30

180 = -180

Is there a quick fix or what could cause the problem?

Regards

Comment: Maybe include the example where the different results 90,-270 occur.

Comment: A $90^\circ$ rotation always has the same result as a $-270^\circ$ rotation about the same axis. They are (for all purposes relevant here) _the same angle_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That is true if you rotate an entire object. If you rotate part of it, i.e. twist the object, those angles are not identical. [In this picture](http://i.imgur.com/kZuwZUP.png) the left object is twisted by 90° and the right object by -270°.

Comment: @SixthOfFour: Yes, but quaternions or matrices cannot represent that distinction. They specify a transformation that you can either do or not do. There is no "apply the transformation halfway".

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are right, of course. I just added that for completeness. (And I admit to still struggling a little with quaternions).